# how to share Linux user passwords and Samba passwords

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, passwd

I have set up a Linux system with its own user account administration.
It is not part of any domain (other than DNS).
Now I want to allow its users to mount their home directories on a Windows system.

One way of doing this is by keeping two user account administrations: one maintained with `passwd`,
the other with `smbpasswd`.  This seems needlessly complicated.  I want to maintain just one.

How can I best arrange this?  The system is running Ubuntu 12.04 (Desktop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PAM](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/pam.html)'s support module for /etc/passwd.

---

Update:

There is a fundamental reason why you cannot unify these authentication mechanisms in any simple way.

- Unix and Linux /etc/passwd authentication requires that the user's password be presented to the server. This can be within an encrypted channel (as in SSH password authentication when not using private-key authentication).
- NTLM and MS-Kerberos authentication don't transmit passwords they transmit a hash of a password and the authenticating server takes it's copy of the user's password, constructs a hash using the same algorithm and compares the hash result with the hash presented by the client. Since /etc/passwd doesn't store passwords and uses a different hashing algorithm, /etc/passwd has insufficient information for authenticating NTLM/Kerberos clients.
- Really old SMB authentication protocols pass the password (in plaintext, i.e. unprotected) and a SMB server can therefore compute a /etc/passwd type hash of this and compare it to the hash stored in /etc/passwd.

From the above it follows that you need a separate file to store passwords (smbpasswd) or a domain controller if you want to avoid plain text passwords transiting your LAN.

Comment: To do what? To replace all use of /etc/passwd with the use of the password file managed by smbpasswd?

Comment: @reinerpost, I had in mind the opposite. Tell Samba to use /etc/passwd (via PAM). This seems a simpler proposition to me :-) The link in my answer points to Samba documentation, not to general Linux documentation.

Comment: I have tried to do that, but it seems to require the Windows client sending the password in cleartext (http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/pam.html#id2667015) or a password synchronization mechanism that appears to work only in one direction (http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/pam.html#id2667199), both rather suboptimal workarounds in my view.

Comment: @reinierpost: So far as I know, the most common solution for that set of requirements (encrypted credentials on wire, single point of user admin) is to authenticate through a Windows Domain Controller (or Samba acting as such).

Comment: That is also my impression, but it would be helpful to know for sure. Hence my question.

Comment: @reinierpost: There is little reason for sync to work in the other direction, since Windows does not support changing passwords over SMB if you're not in a domain (so a desync is next to impossible).

Comment: Hm ... can I set up the box to be its own one-machine Windows domain without interfering with my organizations domain (on which this box, being a Linxu machine, is not allowed)? And to what extent can I get rid of /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow altogether? If I can use Samba passwords for everything (i.e. if all Ubuntu applications I use support PAM), that solution will be fine with me.

Comment: Would [Winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/interfaces#explorer_interface) + public-key authentication be acceptable?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick; Not really. I'm looking for a way to avoid having to ask my colleagues to use some special software on the Windows side. They know how to do scp, that's not the issue.